# multiprocessing is failing in psycopg2 2.8.3 version

Tags: django, multithreading, multiprocessing, psycopg2

I have updated the psycopg2 version to 2.8.3. After doing that multiprocessing connection pool is failing.
Error traceback

```
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/app/project/utils/ddr_algorithm_main.py", line 461, in get_actual_datapoints
    years_in_practice = ddr_obj.get_years_in_practice(single_data_list_static)
  File "/app/project/utils/ddr_report_algorithm.py", line 436, in get_years_in_practice
    provider_data[3])
  File "/app/project/utils/ddr_report_algorithm.py", line 477, in get_single_provider_years_in_practice_list
    list_result = [int(str(i[0]).split(',')[1]) for i in provider_years_in_practice_list if
  File "/app/project/utils/ddr_report_algorithm.py", line 478, in <listcomp>
    i[0] and str(i[0]).split(',').__len__() > 1]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 1994)'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/project/medical_info/management/commands/ddr_data_points.py", line 13, in handle
    ddr_main_class_obj.main()
  File "/app/project/utils/ddr_algorithm_main.py", line 358, in main
    create_datapoints = calculateParallel(provider_ids, threads=30)
  File "/app/project/utils/ddr_algorithm_main.py", line 554, in calculateParallel
    results = pool.map(class_obj.get_actual_datapoints, provider_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 1994)'
```

This is happening after I updated to psycopg2 version 2.8.3

Code snipet

```
def calculateParallel(provider_ids, threads=None):
    for name, info in django.db.connections.databases.items():  # Close the DB connections
        django.db.connection.close()
    pool = ThreadPool(threads)
    class_obj = MainDataClass()
    results = pool.map(class_obj.get_actual_datapoints, provider_ids)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results
```

The reason why I updated the psycopg2 version because multithreading was failing in version psycopg2==2.7.4.

Using psycopg2-binary application works but one of my Django custom management commands fails.

The management command works perfectly on version 2.7.4 but multithreading fails.

On version 2.8.3 multithreading works but management command fails.

I am not sure exactly what I need to change. And I am pretty sure that above error traceback is due to change in psycopg2 version. For older version it works fine.

Code where i am getting the error.

```
    provider_years_in_practice_list = self.query(sql_single_provider_years_in_practice_list)
    if provider_years_in_practice_list:
        list_result = [int(str(i[0]).split(',')[1]) for i in provider_years_in_practice_list if
                                   i[0] and str(i[0]).split(',').__len__() > 1]
        list_result = list(set(list_result))  # remove the year duplications
```

The list "provider_years_in_practice_list" contains the numeric range type elements.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is

```
if provider_years_in_practice_list:
    list_result = [int(i[0].upper) for i in provider_years_in_practice_list if
                           i[0] and i[0].upper]
```